How to clear a ListView that fetches elements from an API when I come back to the activity
So from the ActionActivity, I can start the ListeRecette activity. In the ListeRecette activity, when I click on btnRechercher, it will fill the ListView with elements thanks to an API GET. But when I finish the ListeRecette activity by pressing btnRetour, then start it again from the ActionActivity, the ListView still displays elements and when I click on one of them, it gives me:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.chefchatter, PID: 8171
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
at com.example.chefchatter.activites.ListeRecette$1.onItemClick(ListeRecette.java:96)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1257)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3270)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4236)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
So, I want to ensure that when I start the ListeRecette activity again, that the ListView is empty and doesn't hold any elements for us to click.
package com.example.chefchatter.activites;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.chefchatter.R;
import com.example.chefchatter.activites.ListeRecette;
import com.example.chefchatter.modele.Compte;
import com.example.chefchatter.presentateur.PresentateurCompte;

public class ActionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView tvBonjour;
    private ImageButton imgBtnHome;
    private Button btnDeconnexion;
    private  Button btnParcourirRecettes;
    private Button btnModifierCompte;

    private Button btnFavoris;
    private Compte compte;
    private PresentateurCompte presentateurCompte;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action);

        tvBonjour = findViewById(R.id.tvBonjour);
        btnDeconnexion = findViewById(R.id.btnDeconnexion);
        btnParcourirRecettes = findViewById(R.id.btnParcourirRecettes);
        btnModifierCompte = findViewById(R.id.btnModifierCompte);
        btnFavoris = findViewById(R.id.btnParcourirFavoris);

        btnDeconnexion.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnParcourirRecettes.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnModifierCompte.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnFavoris.setOnClickListener(this);

        presentateurCompte = new PresentateurCompte(this);

    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        compte = presentateurCompte.getCompte();
        if (compte != null) {
            String nomUtilisateur = compte.getNomUtilisateur();
            String messaqeBienvenue = getResources().getString(R.string.bonjour, nomUtilisateur);
            tvBonjour.setText(messaqeBienvenue);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnDeconnexion){
            finish();
        }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnParcourirRecettes){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListeRecette.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnModifierCompte){

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ModifierCompteActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnParcourirFavoris){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListeFavorisActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

package com.example.chefchatter.activites;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.example.chefchatter.dao.RecettesCallback;
import com.example.chefchatter.modele.Filtre;
import com.example.chefchatter.R;
import com.example.chefchatter.modele.Recette;
import com.example.chefchatter.presentateur.AdapteurRecette;
import com.example.chefchatter.presentateur.IngredientsAdapter;
import com.example.chefchatter.presentateur.PresentateurRecette;

import java.util.List;

public class ListeRecette extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btnRetour;
    private Button btnRechercher;

    private ListView listeRecette;

    private Spinner origine;
    private Spinner regime;
    private Spinner type;
    PresentateurRecette presentateurRecette;
    List<Recette> recettes;
    private AdapteurRecette adaptateur;
    private EditText txtIngredient;

    private Filtre filtre = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste_recette);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        origine = findViewById(R.id.sChoixOrigine);
        regime = findViewById(R.id.sChoixRegime);
        type = findViewById(R.id.sChoixType);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterOrigine = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_choice_origine, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterOrigine.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        origine.setAdapter(adapterOrigine);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterRegime = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_choice_regime, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterRegime.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        regime.setAdapter(adapterRegime);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterType = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_choice_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        type.setAdapter(adapterType);

        listeRecette = findViewById(R.id.lvFiltre);

        btnRechercher = findViewById(R.id.btnRecherche);
        btnRechercher.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnRetour = findViewById(R.id.btnRet);
        btnRetour.setOnClickListener(this);

        presentateurRecette = new PresentateurRecette(this);

        adaptateur = new AdapteurRecette(this,
                R.layout.layout_recettes,presentateurRecette);
        listeRecette.setAdapter(adaptateur);

        txtIngredient = findViewById(R.id.etListeIngredients);

        listeRecette.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent iRecetteDescription = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DescriptionRecette.class);
                    Recette recetteSelectionnee = (Recette) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    String src = recetteSelectionnee.getSrc();
                    String nom = recetteSelectionnee.getNom();
                    //ajouter mots clefs
                    Integer idRecette = recetteSelectionnee.getId();
                    String tempsCuisson = recetteSelectionnee.getCuisson();
                    String tempsPreparation = recetteSelectionnee.getPreparation();
                    String portions = recetteSelectionnee.getPortion();
                    String description = recetteSelectionnee.getDescription();
                    String origine = recetteSelectionnee.getOrigine();
                    String regime = recetteSelectionnee.getRegime();
                    String type = recetteSelectionnee.getType();
                    String etape = recetteSelectionnee.getEtape();
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("ID", idRecette);
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("SRC", src);
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("NOM", nom);
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("TEMPS_CUISSON", tempsCuisson);
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("TEMPS_PREPARATION", tempsPreparation);
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("PORTIONS", portions);
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("DESCRIPTION", description);
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("ORIGINE", origine);
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("REGIME", regime);
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("TYPE", type);
                    iRecetteDescription.putExtra("ETAPES", etape);
                    startActivity(iRecetteDescription);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == btnRetour){
            finish();
        }
        else if(v == btnRechercher){

            String[] ingredientsListe = txtIngredient.getText().toString().split(",");
            String[] origineValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_choice_origine_values);
            String[] regimeValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_choice_regime_values);
            String[] typeValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_choice_type_values);

            String origine = this.origine.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 ? "" : origineValues[this.origine.getSelectedItemPosition()];
            String regime = this.regime.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 ? "" : regimeValues[this.regime.getSelectedItemPosition()];
            String type = this.type.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 ? "" : typeValues[this.type.getSelectedItemPosition()];

            filtre = new Filtre(origine, regime, type, ingredientsListe);
            presentateurRecette.obtenirRecettes(filtre ,new RecettesCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onRecettesReceived(List<Recette> recettes) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ListeRecette.this.recettes = presentateurRecette.getRecettes();
                            adaptateur.clear();
                            adaptateur.addAll(recettes);
                            raffraichirListe();
                        }
                    });

                }

            });

    }
 }

    public void raffraichirListe() {
        this.adaptateur.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(this,adaptateur.getCount()+" recettes retrouvées",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Initialize the adapter if null
        if (adaptateur == null) {
            adaptateur = new AdapteurRecette(this, R.layout.layout_recettes, presentateurRecette);
            listeRecette.setAdapter(adaptateur);
        } else {
            adaptateur.clear();
            adaptateur.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

//    @Override
//    protected void onResume() {
//        super.onResume();
//        int r = checkSelfPermission("android.permission.INTERNET");
//        if (r == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//            //    Toast.makeText(this, "Accès Internet permis!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            this.presentateurRecette.obtenirRecettes(filtre, new RecettesCallback() {
//                @Override
//                public void onRecettesReceived(List<Recette> recettes) {
//                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//                        @Override
//                        public void run() {
//                            ListeRecette.this.recettes = presentateurRecette.getRecettes();
//                            adaptateur.clear();
//                            adaptateur.addAll(recettes);
//                            raffraichirListe();
//                        }
//                    });
//
//                }
//            }
//            );
//        } else {
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Accès Internet non permis!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        }
//    }
}

package com.example.chefchatter.presentateur;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.chefchatter.R;
import com.example.chefchatter.modele.Recette;

public class AdapteurRecette extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context contexte;
    private int viewResourceId;
    private Resources resources;
    private PresentateurRecette presentateur;
    public AdapteurRecette(@NonNull Context context, int resource, PresentateurRecette presentateur) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.contexte = context;
        this.viewResourceId = resource;
        this.resources = contexte.getResources();
        this.presentateur = presentateur;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.presentateur.getNbRecettes();
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) contexte.getSystemService(Context.
                    LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(this.viewResourceId, parent, false);
        }
        final Recette recette = this.presentateur.getRecette(position);
        if (recette != null) {
            final TextView tvNomRecette = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lrTvNomRecette);
            final TextView tvPrenomChef = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lrTvPrenomChef);
            final ImageView imageRecette = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.lrIvPhoto);

            tvNomRecette.setText(String.format("Nom de la recette: %s", recette.getNom()));
            tvPrenomChef.setText(String.format("Chef: %s", recette.getPrenom()));
            Glide.with(this.contexte)
                    .load(recette.getSrc())
                    .into(imageRecette);
        }
        return view;
    }

}

Thank you.

Check line no Recette recetteSelectionnee = (Recette) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position); your adapter doesn't have any values in it.

do you mean when you press the btnRetour button at that time activity is finishing and list should be clear as well? Am I right?

change it to this:
else if(v.getId() == R.id.btnParcourirRecettes){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListeRecette.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

